# Android startService Synchronous?

Tags: android, service

I can't find this anywhere in the documentation:

Is a call to context.startService() synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Asynchronous. It will not even begin doing any work until after you return from whatever callback you are in (e.g., `onCreate()`, `onListItemClick()`).

Comment: Then how do I wait till startService() is done as in my case,I am getting a NullPointerException for the service static reference.

Comment: @rahulserver: "Then how do I wait till startService() is done as in my case" -- you don't. You have the service tell you when its work is done (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`). "I am getting a NullPointerException for the service static reference" -- do not make a "service static reference" please. If you have additional questions on this topic, please use the "Ask Question" button to ask one.

Comment: see my question which I have asked just now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081635/android-activity-accessing-services-static-reference-before-the-service-is-read

Comment: This is a *very* old question, still .. per my reading of the docs, `startService()` calls `onStartCommand()` **synchronously**. The javadoc for `startService` says: *Returns: If the service is being started or is already running, the ComponentName of the actual __service that was started is returned__; else if the service does not exist null is returned.*

Comment: @curioustechizen: "startService() calls onStartCommand() synchronously" -- no, it does not. The fact that `startService()` returns a `ComponentName` does not imply that `onStartCommand()` is called synchronously. Moreover, if you actually try it, you will rapidly discover that it is called asynchronously. The `ComponentName` return value means the `Intent` resolution was done synchronously, nothing more.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yikes! you're right. Damn ... my entire life has been a lie!!. I was hoping to use this pattern for having a `Service` register for an EventBus and immediately post an event to it. Looks like I'll have to work around this.